# What is the fastest protocol for transferring small files between a high latency VPN?

Tags: networking, file-sharing, file-transfer

I have ~70ms latency over my VPN connection and need to set up a backup/replication system. SMB is the worst, with throughput ~200KB/s. SCP gives me ~400KB/s. HTTP ~700KB/s. The links are symmetric 50mbit connections.

Is there any kind of file transfer protocol designed for this kind of high latency connection?

Thanks.

Comment: what does ftp look like?

Comment: Stationwagon full of tapes.

Comment: Have you looked at WAN accelerators? Not inexpensive but can really help.

Comment: How many files, and how small? Could be relevant.

Answer (score 5):

If you already have a VPN in-place, then ftp might be a valid choice.

A latency of `~70ms` is not what I would call high though.  SCP and http should perform far better then what you describe on a `50mb/s 70ms` link.  You may have some other problem.  You might want to use iperf or something else that can test the raw capacity of your connection.

Comment: +1 for other problem. I regularly reach over 1MiB/s on 200+ms links. RSS should take care of latency, if there are lots of small files to transfer, than every protocol *will* be slow. `tar` them before transfer. If tarring doesn't help: you've got different problem.

Comment: +1. 70ms rtd is not that much and transfers over a 50Mb/s link shoud really be faster than what the OP states. Other problem here.

Comment: I for one do NOT think that you have another problem! While 70ms is indeed a good value, it still matters a LOT! Especially for small files! There's no way you can transfer more than 10 tiny small files per second, even though you have 50mb/s. Unless you use rsync or tar it. Just calculate one rountrip for open, one for close, one for each chunk for SMB. It really is that bad

Answer (score 3):

I'd use `tar`

you can either create a tarfile and transfer it, or directly pipe the output throught `netcat` or similar tools.

The advantage is that the protocol won't do a lot of file-open handshakes.

Answer (score 2):

I would probably use scp or rsync and the arcfour cipher.

Comment: If that's too tricky, robocopy can be setup to wait/retry if the connection drops, but robocopy is only clever enough to overwrite the whole of any changed file rather than just the changes.